# Windows 10 BSOD

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod

I just recently built myself a new computer. I put all the parts together, installed windows 10, and everything worked fine, until I tried to play a game. I then got the BSOD one started corrupted hardware faulty page, ava another started memory exception. Help please.

Comment: I suspect bad or incompatible memory modules. [Use Memtest](http://www.memtest.org/), run it overnight to stress test the memory modules, see if it shows any errors next day.

Comment: It's very possible you have a bad stick(s) of memory and/or a bad memory timing/speed configuration error in the BIOS....I agree with @Moab run memtest and let it run overnight and see if it shows errors (they will be in red).

Comment: copy the folder **C:\Windows\Minidump**, to the desktop, zip and upload the folder to your Onedrive, create a share link and post a link here.

Comment: Ok I've run MemTest and it came back with 7 errors in my RAM I believe. Since it find it in an 8gb portion of memory. Does that mean my memory is incompatible.

Comment: it means the RAM is damaged. replace the module with a new RAM module